Squish 2 gates into 1 cell
Does anybody know a way to squish 2 gates into one column with quantikz?
Take this circuit for example:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}[column sep=0.1cm]
    & \gate{X} & \gate{Y} & \\
    & \gate{(X+Y)/2} & &
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}

Is it possible to squish the 2 gates for the upper qubit together such that they take up the same space as the wider gate on the bottom qubit?

Stretching the lower gate across 2 cells would have the same visual effect I guess.
